# Nexus doesn't update metadata for SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven, jenkins, sbt, ivy, nexus

My setup is a jenkins that polls my git repo and does publish to a nexus repo on each push. Then I have a downstream project that takes this artifact and deploys it to a test server. This project is using artifact resolver plugin for jenkins and just uses "LATEST" as version.

What I notice is the following. After I have published a new snapshot the metadata is only updated in the specific version folder. The specific version metadata is correct:

https://repo.woodenstake.se/content/repositories/snapshots/se/uniply/dfkka_2.10/1.2.7-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml:

```
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
<groupId>se.uniply</groupId>
<artifactId>dfkka_2.10</artifactId>
<version>1.2.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
<versioning>
<lastUpdated>20130524112854</lastUpdated>
</versioning>
</metadata>
```

https://repo.woodenstake.se/content/repositories/snapshots/se/uniply/dfkka_2.10/maven-metadata.xml

shows an old timestamp:

```
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
<groupId>se.uniply</groupId>
<artifactId>dfkka_2.10</artifactId>
<versioning>
<latest>1.2.7-SNAPSHOT</latest>
<release/>
<versions>
<version>1.2.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
</versions>
<lastUpdated>20130523200733</lastUpdated>
</versioning>
</metadata>
```

Therefore artifact resolver doesn't download the latest version but just uses the cached one from a local directory. Why doesn't Nexus update the version? Is there any setting I missed?

More info:

I'm using sbt 12.2 with publish plugin (ivy under the hood).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked about this in the SBT google group too:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/simple-build-tool/ErA1ybeRXec

After doing some more research this thread

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/simple-build-tool/okaoV3SDH24

seems to state that its Ivy that doesn't PUT these files in the way that is expected when using Maven. A solution is to use an Aether-plugin for SBT that "deploys" the Maven way instead of "publish".

https://github.com/arktekk/sbt-aether-deploy

Using this one, the xml:s got updated too with PUT:s from the SBT build.

Answer (score 1):

Nexus does not in fact maintain these files at all. The build system does that. If you are using Maven the deploy plugin will take care of it.

It seems sbt with ivy is not doing that properly. I would suggest to integrate the sbt-aether-deploy tool as suggested by @hedefalk.

As a stop gap measure you can run the rebuild metadata task on the repository regularly.

Comment: I actually tried the rebuild metadata, but it didn't seem to work for me as I recall. Anyway, the aether-deploy plugin is working brilliantly for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers related ivy and Maven snapshot releases:

- [Publishing Ivy SNAPSHOTS with Maven metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771776/publishing-ivy-snapshots-with-maven-metadata/15797166#15797166)
- [What's wrong with this Ivy changingPattern / SNAPSHOT configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445268/whats-wrong-with-this-ivy-changingpattern-snapshot-configuration/14445694#14445694)

In summary, snapshot releases are a Maven feature not completely supported by ivy.