# How to make ivy stop re-resolving dependencies?

Tags: ivy

How does one make Ivy resolve, retrieve, and **freeze** dynamic dependencies until the process is manually triggered again?  I'm thinking of the case where someone is building release candidates and wants to insulate the build from all unnecessary changes.

I'm currently experimenting with a project that depends upon the `latest.integration` revision of another project.  In my ivy.xml file I have this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency name="mylib" rev="latest.revision"/>
</dependencies>
```

For compilation, I put mylib onto the classpath in this way:

```
<ivy:cachepath organisation="myorg"
               module="mylib"
               revision="latest.integration"
               pathid="mylib.jar.path.id"
               inline="true"/>
    <property name="file.reference.mylib.jar"
              refid="mylib.jar.path.id"/>
</ivy:cachepath>
```

But, if I push a newer version of mylib to the repository and rebuild my project, this `<ivy:cachepath>` task will re-resolve and re-retrieve mylib, which is exactly the opposite of what I want it to do.

I have tried `<ivy:resolve>`, but it does not have the freezing effect I am looking for.

If this is just how Ivy works, that is OK.  I'll just make the output of resolution write all the paths to a .properties file, and use the contents of that .properties file during compilation rather than all the Ivy business.

But, before I go down that path, I want to be sure I am not just misusing Ivy, as this seems like a use case that should be built in.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [deliver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/deliver.html) task. For examples of its use:

- [Automate ivy revision increase for all my projects using ant script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384024/automate-ivy-revision-increase-for-all-my-projects-using-ant-script/8392205#8392205)
- [Convert ivy.xml to pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426011/convert-ivy-xml-to-pom-xml/9429286#9429286)

I think you should also consider using a Maven repository manager that supports staging and promotion of artifacts. That way you build them once and use them continuously.